# JavaScript create element with animation. JavaScript rewrite sourcecode

Tags: javascript, html

So, this is the sourcecode on a webpage I made. So is there any way how I could create the same result with JavaScript?

Or other way could be, if I could rewrite the source code. If u know what I mean.

```css
body {
  background-color: #002b36;
}

div {
  height: 645px;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation-name: rbg;
  animation-duration: 15s;
}
@keyframes rbg {
  2% {background-color: red}
  16% {background-color: orange}
  32% {background-color: yellow}
  41% {background-color: lawngreen}
  62% {background-color: cyan}
  81% {background-color: indigo}
  92% {background-color: mediumvioletred}
  100% {background-color: deeppink}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rainbow</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add more context on why you want to do that in Javascript ? It seams to be working fine in CSS.

Comment: So I have my webpage, there is a button. When the button is clicked I want this result to show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the same `animation` result with `Javascript`:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');

div.animate([{
  backgroundColor: "red",
}, {
 backgroundColor: "orange",
}, {
 backgroundColor: "yellow",
}, {
 backgroundColor: "lawngreen",
}, {
 backgroundColor: "cyan",
}, {
 backgroundColor: "indigo",
}, {
 backgroundColor: "mediumvioletred",
}, {
 backgroundColor: "deeppink",
}], {
  duration: 15000,
  iterations: Infinity
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #002b36;
}

div {
  height: 645px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
    <div></div>
```

**There is a great article for the animate Method [here](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/web_animations_animate_method.htm)**

Comment: Alternatively: `div.animate({backgroundColor: ["red","orange","yellow","lawngreen","cyan","indigo","mediumvioletred","deeppink"]}, {duration: 15000, iterations: Infinity});` -- you can either pass an array of keyframes, or a map of properties to keyframes.

Comment: Might want to at least give some indication of the [limited use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate#Browser_compatibility) for `.animate` since it is still "experimental". I guess letting others do it in a comment always works too =/

Comment: I linked an article that covers that and marked it bold. But yes maybe I could have made it a bit more obvious. Thanks for your comment though!

Comment: Thx it works! This is a dumb question, but does this work like:  var div = document.createElement("div");    and then your code to animate it?

Comment: You would have to append the new created div to your body as well:                  let body = document.body;
let div = document.createElement("div");
body.appendChild(div);